# How to fix this eloquent database query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

The codes below needs a lot of rework. I wanted to DRY things up and add only paginate and sort if it is set in options. Do you have any recommendations to fix this?

I have tried doing a manual pagination, but it returns an array instead of an object so my index page breaks.

UserController:

```
// Search term

$src = Request::get('src');

$sort_by = Request::get('sort_by');
$sort_type = Request::get('sort');
$limit = Request::get('limit');

$users = $this->users->search(['email','username','status'], $src, ['paginate' => ['limit' => 5], 'sort' => ['by' => $sort_by, 'type' => $sort_type]]);
```

UserRepository:

```
public function search($fields, $search_term, $options = array())
{
    $users = NULL;

    if (is_array($fields))
    {
        // Check if the user wants to paginate it
        if (isset($options['paginate']))
        {
            $this->pagination_limit = $options['paginate']['limit'];

            $users = User::orWhere(function($query) use ($fields, $search_term) {
                foreach($fields as $field)
                {
                    $query->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', "%$search_term%");
                }
            })->paginate($this->pagination_limit);
        }
        // Return un-paginated result
        else
        {
            $users = User::orWhere(function($query) use ($fields, $search_term) {
                foreach($fields as $field)
                {
                    $query->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', "%$search_term%");
                }
            })->get();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new \Exception('Fields must be an in the form of array.');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is $src ? Can you indent your code properly ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is make a `scopeSearch` method on the User model which lets you just call `$query->search($searchFor)` anywhere - that'll save you a lot of lines of code. Read about scope method [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes). You could also do the same for sorting if you wanted.

The second thing I'd do, but this is just my opinion, is implement search, sort, paginate etc as chainable methods by making the repository a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). I found a good SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414042/2490608) explaining in depth how to make a fluent interface in PHP.

You don't have to implement a fluent interface, but I find it's good for achieving DRY, and the alternative of passing huge arrays (or even an object) of data with search terms, filters and sort parameters quickly gets messy.